# Injective homomorphism induced by cup product in cohomology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, calabi-yau, holomorphic-symplectic

Let $M$ be an irreducible holomorphic symplectic manifold of dimension $\geq 4$. In his paper 'A survey of Torelli and Monodromy results', Markman claims (discussion after Theorem 9.7) that the cup product
$$ \cup:\,H^2(M,\mathbb{Q})\otimes H^2(M,\mathbb{Q})\longrightarrow H^4(M,\mathbb{Q})$$
induces an injective homomorphism
$$ Sym^2\left(H^2(M,\mathbb{Q})\right)\longrightarrow H^4(M,\mathbb{Q})$$
by a general result due to Verbitsky. This result is said to be in the paper 'Cohomology of compact hyper-Kahler manifolds and its applications', without specifying where. I have found this paper free on arxiv, http://arxiv.org/pdf/alg-geom/9511009.pdf (but it is useless without this other one http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.52.4243&rep=rep1&type=pdf ).

I guess the claim follows, in some way, from the discussion given at the end of Section 5.1 Mirror Symmetry (end of page 7 and beginning of page 8 in the first link above) but I cannot be sure because I am not able to do computations in this setting (working with Lie algebras associated to Lefschez-Frobenius algebras, etc..). In particular, I am unaware about the sentence "Yukawa multiplication
is equal to the cup-product in cohomology twisted by $\eta$" and if this should help.

Can anyone suggest me if this is the right way and, in case, give me the idea for such an implication? Otherwise, if this is not the right way, do you maybe know where to look for?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: More generally, the homomorphism $Sym^pH^2(M,\mathbb{Q})\rightarrow H^{2p}(M,\mathbb{Q})$ is injective for $2p\leq \dim M$: this is proved in Bogomolov's paper *On the cohomology ring of a
simple hyperkähler manifold (on the results of Verbitsky)*, Geom.
Funct. Anal. **6** (1996),  612-618.

Comment: Dear abx, I have taken time to look at Bogomolov's paper. Thank you very much, I've got the required injectivity now.

Comment: Anyway, I still have a question. In Bogomolov's argument it seems to me that the hypothesis $M$ is Hyperkahler is very important. On the other hand, Verbitsky's argument (at least where I thought it answers the question) seems to work for Calabi-Yau manifolds in general. Is it?